# react routing always showing the content of "/" route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've just started continuing my react app today but suddenly the routing is not working. whatever url I put in, it always shows the component inside `path="/"`, which is the `Hello World` in `Test1.js`. I'm using `react-router-dom` version 6.2.2

this is my code:

App.js

```
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Test1 from "./components/Test1";
import Test2 from "./components/Test2";

const App = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />

      <div className="container hero is-fullheight">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Test1 />} />
          <Route path="/asd" element={<Test2 />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Test1.js

```
const Test1 = () => {
  return <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>;
};

export default Test1;
```

Test2.js

```
const Test2 = () => {
  return (
    <div><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2></div>
  )
}

export default Test2
```

any help is appreciated..

Comment: Code runs without issue in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routing-always-showing-the-content-of-route-7jkzf0). Are you seeing any errors? What debugging steps have you taken? Have you quit/killed any code-watchers/hot-reloaders and restarted your app from scratch, `npm start`? Are you sure you've installed RRDv6? From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom` and report back the installed version.

Comment: I don't see any errors in the developer tools.. I've tried re-running `npm start`, I'm not using any watchers/hot-reloaders (I don't even know what they are), and I commented most of my previous code and turned it into the above code because I think it's the most basic form of routing

Comment: I see no overt issue in the code you've shared. Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BrowserRouter instead HashRouter

Comment: Are you just guessing what the issue may be and posting anything you think of without explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
...
  <div className="container hero is-fullheight">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Test1 />} />
      <Route path="asd" element={<Test2 />} />  --> // Here the path without slash
    </Routes>
  </div>
...
```

At /asd it will render the Test2 component.

[Doc here.](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#add-some-routes)